# Android Age Verification Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

What would be used in a Age verification Activity? And how would I do it? The thought never crossed my mind and I have no clue where to start ... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is it you want help with more exactly? Is what views you should use in the activity or is it rather on how to do age-verification?

Comment: What do you mean by age verification? If you want a valid date you can use date picker.

Comment: I need my main activity to ask user to enter Age and if they are below a certain age the app uninstall its self ... if they are above the age proceed to next activity.

Comment: Ok, i have learnt that a Calender is along the lines of what I need, but now i need to figure how to compare the values in the calender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask for and check a credit card number.

Comment: No I want to ensure that Minors don't use and abuse the application.